# Regex match (\w+) to capture single words delimited by |||

Tags: python, regex, loops, freeze

I am trying to match if there's singe word followed by `\s|||\s` and then another single word followed by `\s|||\s` so I'm using this regex:

```
single_word_regex = r'(\w+)+\s\|\|\|\s(\w+)\s\|\|\|\s.*'
```

And when I tried to match this string, the regex matching hangs or take minutes (possibly going into some sort of "deep loop")

```
>>> import re
>>> import time
>>> single_word_regex = r'(\w+)+\s\|\|\|\s(\w+)\s\|\|\|\s.*'        
>>> x = u'amornratchatchawansawangwong ||| amornratchatchawansawangwong . ||| 0.594819 0.5 0.594819 0.25 ||| 0-0 0-1 ||| 1 1 1 ||| |||'
>>> z = u'amor 我 ||| amor . i ||| 0.594819 0.0585231 0.594819 0.0489472 ||| 0-0 0-1 1-2 ||| 2 2 2 ||| |||'
>>> y = u'amor ||| amor ||| 0.396546 0.0833347 0.29741 0.08 ||| 0-0 0-1 ||| 3 4 2 ||| |||'
>>> re.match(single_word_regex, z, re.U)                                              
>>> re.match(single_word_regex, y, re.U)                                          
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105b879c0>
>>> start = time.time(); re.match(single_word_regex, y, re.U); print time.time() - start
9.60826873779e-05
>>> start = time.time(); re.match(single_word_regex, x, re.U); print time.time() - start # It hangs...
```

**Why is it taking that long?**

Is there a better/simpler regex to capture this condition`len(x.split(' ||| ')[0].split()) == 1 == len(x.split(' ||| ').split())`?

Comment: `(\w+)+` is evil, remove the last `+`.

Comment: Indeed evil. Now it works with the `(\w+)`. @SebastianProske care to explain why?

Comment: Well, if `\w+` means _char*x_, then `(\w+)+` means _char*x*y_. When the regex engine processes the second, there could be multiple combinations of _x_ and _y_ that work, so it might get hung trying to find a single solution. I don't know the details of the engine, but it isn't really a valid/well-defined thing to parse.

Comment: Should it be `(\w)+` or should it be `(\w+)` ?

Comment: `(\w+)` will capture all of the word characters, `(\w)+` will capture a single word character repeatedly. The first one you get one string captured, the second one you get each character captured individually as it's own capture group.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html might be a helpful link as to avoiding regexp hanging. tl;dr be careful with regex grouping, because it can behave in unexpected ways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by itself, a `r'(\w+)+'` pattern will not cause the [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), it will only be "evil" inside a longer expression and especially when it is placed next to the start of the pattern since in case subsequent subpatterns fail the engine backtracks to this one, and as the 1+ quantifier inside is again quantified with `+`, that creates a huge amount of possible variations to try before failing. You may have a look at [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ZOhPi/1) and click the *regex debugger* on the left to see example regex engine behavior.

The current regex can be written as

```
r'^(\w+)\s\|{3}\s(\w+)\s\|{3}\s(.*)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8amfjD/2) where there will be a match if you remove space and `.` in the second field.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string (not necessary with `re.match`)
- `(\w+)` - (Group 1) 1+ letters/digits/underscores
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `\|{3}` - 3 pipe symbols
- `\s(\w+)\s\|{3}\s` - see above (`(\w+)` creates Group 2)
- `(.*)` - (Group 3) any 0+ characters other than linebreak characters.